# Not able to block all http connection in android

Tags: android, http

I have to disable all http requests in my android app. To achieve that I tried adding the following in the network config file after reading this(https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#base-config):

```
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
```

This is not working as expected when I tested in Android 7. It is working in Android 8 and above.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you also need to add an attribute to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. You can add this attribute to block HTTP requests:

```
<application ....
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="false"
</application>
```

Since you have already modified your network config file too, this should be sufficient.